# Prove that a matrix doesn't exist with a given characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations

I've been trying to understand this following issue:

> Show that a matrix A, where $\rho(A) = 3$ doesn't exist,
>
> Where the characteristic polynomial is: $p(x) = x^7 - x^5 + x^3$

I've disassembled the polynomial to be: $p(x) = x^3(x^2(x^2 -1) + 1)$. It seems like it cannot be disassembled over $\mathbb R$.

I'm not sure how does the information of the matrix being from rank 3 plays in, if there aren't any eigenvalues to the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the dimension of the kernel (AKA nullspace) of $A$ is given by $7 - \rho(A) = 4$. However, the nullspace of $A$ is also an eigenspace of $A$.

Comment: I see, so that would mean that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ is 4.
Also, you concluded that the dimension is $n$, as the first term in the polynomial is in the power of 7... I'm trying to connect the dots. I guess it would not be valid if the algebric multiplicity is less than the geometric. But I feel a bit lost on how to find it.. Maybe because of my disassembling, it has to be 3?

Comment: @EatayMizrachi Yes, that's exactly right. The algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the exponent of $(x - \lambda)$ in the disassembled characteristic polynomial $p(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

$p(x)=x^3(x^4-x^2+1)$ which has a triple root at $0$ and four simple roots at $$\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\pm i\sqrt3}2}$$ (The second factor is a quadratic in $x^2$.)

Since eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent, $A$, considered as a complex matrix, has rank $4$.  But [the rank of a matrix doesn't change if we make the ground field bigger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405573/rank-of-a-matrix-in-the-real-and-complex-field), so the rank of A is $4$ over the reals also.